# How to Show Same Month name of two years in X axis of Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a Highcharts chart in my application. I need to display how many cars have been sold in each month of the year and this chart shows car selling over 13 months time period(Ex: June 2017- June 2018) so that same month(of two years) is displayed two times. X category should be something like (Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun)

But the problem is chart shows only one "Jun" month in the graph. I think category name duplication is the error. Is there a workaround for this to get done?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Car Sales'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent car salee'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },

    "series": [
        {
            "name": "Browsers",
            "colorByPoint": true,
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "January",
                    "y": 62.74,
                },
                {
                    "name": "February",
                    "y": 10.57,
                },
                {
                    "name": "March",
                    "y": 7.23,
                },
                {
                    "name": "April",
                    "y": 5.58,
                },
                {
                    "name": "May",
                    "y": 4.02,
                },
                {
                    "name": "June",
                    "y": 1.92,
                },
                {
                    "name": "July",
                    "y": 7.62,
                },
                {
                    "name": "August",
                    "y": 7.62,
                },
                {
                    "name": "September",
                    "y": 7.62,
                },
                {
                    "name": "October",
                    "y": 7.62,
                },
                {
                    "name": "November",
                    "y": 7.62,
                },
                {
                    "name": "December",
                    "y": 7.62,
                },
                {
                    "name": "January",
                    "y": 7.62,
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/yasirunilan/2ryfnv3q/

Comment: Can you please add in the code? Right now we can't reproduce the error.

Comment: This is the code, https://jsfiddle.net/yasirunilan/2ryfnv3q/ even though I have two January months it shows up in same column in the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get to achieve this inside the drilldown, is to 'cheat' with the name of the category. If you are able to add in a space (or any other random character) at the end of the second `Jan` in the drilldown, it will solve the problem.

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/2ryfnv3q/19/) for a fiddle demonstrating the solution.

```
 "drilldown": {
        "series": [
            {
                "name": "Chrome",
                "id": "Chrome",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "name": "Jan",
                        "y": 0.1
                    },
                    {
                       "name": "Feb",
                        "y": 0.1
                    },
                    //snip
                    {
                        "name": "Jan ",
                        "y": 0.1
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Comment: But there is a problem like this, Initially, I can't define the category types as I have a drill down too. https://jsfiddle.net/yasirunilan/2ryfnv3q/15/

Comment: @YasiruNilan That is quite a critical detail you didn't mention in your question. Please edit that in to reflect it. Meanwhile I will take a look

Comment: That seems to work.But the problem is in my scenario I Don't know what are the category names initially. Month names could be from Jan-Jan or April-April. So I don't know exactly when a month will get repeated to add a space or any thing

Comment: @YasiruNilan Please edit your question to put in all of these kinds of details. I am reluctant right now to update my answer again because I have no clue what all your requirements are. Additionally, you are generating the data yourself (afaik) so you should be able to add a space to like the last month in the array.

Comment: Thanks it helped.